# Is there a way to format this string more efficiently?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I want to format this text with tuples using the `format` method and was wondering if there is a better way to do it...

```
data = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

output_text = "KP: {}\nData 1: {}\nData 2: {}\nData 3: {}\nData 4: {}\nData 5: {}\n".format(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5])
```

Comment: Yes. `.format(*data)`

Comment: Do you mean efficiently as in speed or as in _developer efficiency_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `*` operator to unpack `data` as in `<format str>.format(*data)`

```
>>> data = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> "KP: {}\nData 1: {}\nData 2: {}\nData 3: {}\nData 4: {}\nData 5: {}\n".format(*data)
'KP: 1\nData 1: 2\nData 2: 3\nData 3: 4\nData 4: 5\nData 5: 6\n'
```

To simplify it further and make it work for any arbitrary length, you can use `enumerate` and `chain` like the following

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> ('Data {}: {}\n' * len(data)).format(*chain(*enumerate(data)))
'Data 0: 1\nData 1: 2\nData 2: 3\nData 3: 4\nData 4: 5\nData 5: 6\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use a lot of python syntax in the string formatting.

```py
>>> data = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> "KP: {data[0]}\nData 1: {data[1]}\nData 2: {data[2]}\nData 3: {data[3]}"
    "\nData 4: {data[4]}\nData 5: {data[5]}\n".format(data=data)
```